# Android Xamarin - Align control right with right margin in RelativeLayout

Tags: c#, android, xml, android-layout, xamarin

I'm using a RelativeLayout to display my UI.

I want to have a title on the top left and I want an image on the top right.
Both items need to have a small spacing above and to the side (either left or right).

For my title, this works great, but I can't seem to be able to both align my image to the right and also set a right margin.

This is the axml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dialogContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:paddingBottom="25dip">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dialogTitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:textColor="#158849"
    android:textSize="25dip" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/dialogLoading"
    android:layout_width="26dip"
    android:layout_height="26dip"
    android:background="@drawable/LoadingAnimation"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
    android:layout_marginRight="25dip" /> <!--this doesn't work, there is no spacing-->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dialogMessage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="18dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dialogTitle" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Other things that might be of help: 
this project should be buildable against Android 2.3

I'm not directly assigning this layout to an activity.

Instead, this is used as a view for a custom dialog.

Answer (score 2):

use the relative layout's `layout_toLeftOf` propperty:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dialogContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:paddingBottom="25dip">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialogTitle"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:textColor="#158849"
        android:textSize="25dip"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/dialogTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dialogTitle"
        android:layout_width="26dip"
        android:layout_height="26dip"
        android:background="@drawable/LoadingAnimation"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
<!--this doesn't work, there is no spacing-->
</RelativeLayout>
```

updated my answer

Comment: So you're saying: I need to put my image "to the left of" my title? And then create a margin to push my image to the right? My title is variable, so my size would change as well...

Comment: It should allays be to the left of the image, no matter the content length (i think - haven't played a lot with relative layout) - you can easily test that.. It's a relative layout each layout inside is positioned in relation to other (another) layout.

Comment: you do not need to create a margin for the other layout (the imageview) - just set align parent top and right to true for it - since the parent is the Relative layout itself...

Comment: But I want my imageview to be pressed against the right side with a little margin. It should not be dependent on whatever the left control (the title) is doing

Comment: yes it should be with `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` (parent being Relative layout itself)

Comment: I'm still not getting it. My image is pressed against the right side already. This is correct BUT I also want a space between the image and the right side (Layout_MarginRight)?